# Why does the "Dopplr’s coloring algorithm" produce a color?

Tags: graphics, md5, color-space

I stumbled over this [blogpost](http://optional.is/required/2010/12/13/hls-world-map/) by Brian Suda and quickly applied the "Dopplr’s coloring algorithm" to some examples, and that this works is not in question. What is, is why?

The process is as follows:

```
$hex_color = sub-string(md5($original_string), 0, 6)
```

Input some string (e.g. city names as with dopplr's original usage), make a [md5-hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#MD5_hashes) of this, and use the first 6 digits from the hash. Prepend this with a "#" and a string is transformed into a color fit for use in CSS-documents etc.

How is it that the six first digits of a md5-hash always matches a color in the hexadecimal representation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD5 always outputs hex.  Colors can be represented as a 6-character hex string in css.  So, the MD5 hash is just producing a semi-random hex string.

And any hex string (that is 6 characters long and begins with a `#`) is valid to define a color.